# I can't get my GPUs to work

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, amdgpu, amdgpu-pro

I recently got a new laptop with an integrated AMD gpu and a dedicated Nvidia GTX gpu, I decided to make it a Windows/Ubuntu dual boot. I'm doing a bit of GPU programming so I would like to get at least one of the cards working with OpenCL/OpenGL, if possible the Nvidia card, and it would be even better if I could have both working.

When I installed Ubuntu, I had a few problems with the Nvidia driver causing freezes and login loops, but I fixed it with `prime-select intel` (I don't understand what "intel" means in the command since I don't have an intel gpu).
At this moment, I think my amd gpu was detected, since I could login into gnome without a problem, but it wasn't detected by OpenCl, so I decided to install the amdgpu-pro driver.

After reboot, I would get stuck on a blank screen just after the grub menu. I fiddled around a bit in recovery mode (since I hadn't touched kernel modules before it's possible I broke a few things at that point, though I'm 99% sure I didn't affect things other then the gpu drivers) and after a bit a added `nomodeset` to the kernel command line, this allowed me to continue boot up to the login screen. I'm now stuck on a login loop for my Ubuntu desktop environment, ecen when I uninstall amdgpu-pro, but I can login into i3wm just fine.

From what I understand I have an error in my drivers, creating the blank screen when booting with mode settings, and crashing Xorg, which is why I get a login loop when trying to login into Ubuntu. I also get an error when trying to launch failsafeX in recovery mode.

My GPUs :

```
$ sudo lshw -c video     
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: 3D controller
       product: GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:f000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Raven Ridge [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: c4
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f01fffff ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7700000-f777ffff
```

Errors in Xorg.0.log after I try to login into Ubuntu :

```
[   364.970] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[   364.970] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[   364.970] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[   364.970] xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
[   364.970] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[   364.970] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[   364.970] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[   364.970] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[   364.970] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[   364.970] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[   364.970] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   364.970]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 0.0.2
[   364.970]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[   364.970] (**) FBDEV(1): claimed PCI slot 4@0:0:0
[   364.970] (II) FBDEV(1): using default device
[   364.970] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[   364.970] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[   364.970] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[   364.970] (II) FBDEV(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[   364.970] (==) FBDEV(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[   364.970] (==) FBDEV(0): RGB weight 888
--
[   364.971] (==) FBDEV(0): Backing store enabled
[   364.971] (==) FBDEV(0): DPMS enabled
[   364.972] (==) RandR enabled
[   364.976] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[   364.976] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI2 capable
[   364.976] (EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
[   364.988] (EE) AIGLX error: amdgpu does not export required DRI extension
[   364.988] (EE) GLX: could not load software renderer
[   364.988] (II) GLX: no usable GL providers found for screen 0
[   365.030] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event3)
[   365.030] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   365.030] (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
[   365.030] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
```

Errors in Xorg.failsafe.log:

```
[    18.074] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libint10.so
[    18.074] (II) Module int10: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    18.074]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
[    18.074]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[    18.074] (II) VESA(0): initializing int10
[    18.075] (EE) VESA(0): Cannot read int vect
[    18.075] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    18.075] (II) UnloadSubModule: "int10"
[    18.075] (II) Unloading int10
[    18.075] (II) UnloadSubModule: "vbe"
[    18.075] (II) Unloading vbe
[    18.075] (EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
[    18.075] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[    18.075] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[    18.075] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[    18.075] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.failsafe.log" for additional information.
[    18.075] (EE) 
[    18.086] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

I also found a few errors related to gpu in syslog and dmesg, but I'm not sure which ones are relevant and which ones aren't.

Anyone has an idea what I should do next? I'm a little bit stuck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The "unclaimed" means the Nvidia drivers aren't installed and/or not being used. Install them and disable Secure Boot. But what you want to do isn't possible with hybrid graphics anyway because only one will work, not simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think the Nvidia drivers are already installed because when I do `lspci -k` I get
```
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1)
 Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile]
 Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
```
I don't know about disabling Secure boot, it seems like an unsafe thing to do, how do I check that it is indeed Secure Boot that prevents the drivers from loading? Also like I said I have the `nomodeset` kernel parameter, isn't this what is preventing the drivers from loading?

Comment: I also don't understand what you mean by "what you want isn't possible"? What I want is, as is the case on Windows, being able to use a different gpu for different applications, I can do that on Windows just fine, is there a restriction on Linux that prevents me from doing that? Or are you talking about something else?

Comment: No, lspci lists all devices by their vendor ID and product ID and list what their firmware replies, it doesn't tell you whether the drivers are installed or not and they aren't if you didn't install them. Just open Additional Drivers and you should see a list of additional proprietary Nvidia drivers. No, disabling Secure Boot is no problem and it does prevent loading any unsigned drivers. You can be certain of that if you Google, just a bit. It's unusual for someone attempting to use such advanced features/settings - irrespective of feasibility - and knowing so little to start with. >>>

Comment: >>> I suggest you take some time to learn about Nvidia graphics and its drivers, how they work and should be installed in Ubuntu, UEFI and its Secure Boot feature, etc.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into that!

Comment: No, you can't do that in Windows either. The default state is using the iGPU and any app set to use high performance will trigger a **switch** to use the dGPU. Only one works at any given time. On certain desktops yes, you can use more than one graphics card simultaneously because they're independent and one or more may be tasked with computational task only and not output to any monitor.